# Add bind mount folder to docker container, terraform syntax

Tags: docker, terraform

I want to convert the following `docker` command to `Terraform` syntax:

```
docker run --name mysql -v ~/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d arm64v8/mysql:tag
```

I prepared the following `main.tf` file and executed command `terraform plan` on it

```
terraform {
required_providers {
    docker = {
    source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    version = "~> 3.0.1"
    }
}
}

provider "docker" {}

resource "docker_image" "mysql" {
name         = "arm64v8/mysql:8.0.33"
keep_locally = true
}

resource "docker_container" "mysql" {
image = docker_image.mysql.image_id
name  = "mysql"

mounts ={
    target = "/var/lib/mysql"
    source = "~/db/mysql"
    type   = "bind"
}

env = [
    "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw",
]
}
```

The following error occurs: `An argument named "mounts" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "mounts"?`

How do I properly define bind mounts in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Terraform says "a block of type `mounts`" it means the same sort of thing as the `resource` block you have that setting embedded in, with the following syntax:

```
  mounts {
    target = "/var/lib/mysql"
    source = "~/db/mysql"
    type   = "bind"
  }
```

In your configuration you wrote an argument named `mounts` and tried to assign an object value to it, which despite the similar syntax is not the same thing as a nested `mounts` block with its own independent settings.

The important difference between an argument and a nested block is that an argument can have any expression assigned to it; you happened to use an object constructor expression, but an argument could also be defined using a function call, an arithmetic operator, etc. A nested block, on the other hand, is *always* a braced collection of other arguments and nested blocks, with no option of assigning an expression to it.

There's more information on these language constructs in [Arguments and Blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/syntax/configuration#arguments-and-blocks).